# Play framework + React, namespaces

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0, reactjs

I'd like to ask for opinions/suggestions about folder structure and namespaces for a project I'm working on. It's a Play Framework 2.0, and React+Backbone for the UI.

Current structure:

```
/assets
  /css
  /js
    /lib
      someLib.js
    /models
      bar.js
    /ui
      /components
        Foo.jsx
      App.jsx
      router.jsx
    main.js
```

I have my `/assets/js` folder. Within it I have `main.js` where I'm bootstraping my app.

```
// main.js
import router from './ui/router';
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', router);
```

`router.jsx` contains my routes used by `react-router` and also import of some main components used by those routes.

```
// router.jsx
import App from './App';
import Foo from './components/Foo';

...
const Routes = {
  <ReactRouter.Route handler={App} path="/">
     <ReactRouter.Route name="foo" path="foo" handler={Foo} />
  </ReactRouter.Route>
}

export default function() {
    ReactRouter.run(
        Routes,
        ReactRouter.HistoryLocation,
        function(Handler) {
            React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
        }
    );
}
```

I have also Backbone models which are wired with React and store them in `/assets/js/models`.
E.g.

```
// Foo.jsx 
import bar from './../../models/bar';

..
// some react code
export default Foo;
```

And my model file:

```
// bar.js
import someLib from './../lib/someLib';

..
// some backbone model code
export default Bar;
```

This is it. The things I don't really like are those long paths like
`import API from '../../../api/websocket';` or
`import API from '../../../api/websocket';`

I also would like to avoid referencing `ReactRouter.Route` but just `Route` etc.

I was thinking about some centre point of import/export, but not sure what is the best practice in that kind of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app layout looks ok to me. Don't refactor until you need to.

Your paths can be cleaned up by avoiding redundant `./` so use `../../models/bar` instead of `./../../models/bar`.

With `ReactRouter.Route` I find it useful to go to https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html and see how your code looks once it's been transpiled to normal JS. Take your Route as an example:

```
const Routes = (
  <ReactRouter.Route handler={App} path="/">
     <ReactRouter.Route name="foo" path="foo" handler={Foo} />
  </ReactRouter.Route>
)
```

Compiles to:

```
const Routes = (
  React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {handler: App, path: "/"}, 
     React.createElement(ReactRouter.Route, {name: "foo", path: "foo", handler: Foo})
  )
)
```

So you can see that `ReactRouter.Route` is just a normal object that gets passed in to `React.createElement`. That means that you can name it whatever you want. You could do `const Route = ReactRouter.Route;` or export that from a module and import it like `import { Route } from '../lib/MyReactUtils'` etc...